# OpenBSD httpd.conf conditionals

Tags: webserver, openbsd, http, openbsd-httpd

*Note: this question is about the [built-in OpenBSD http server named `httpd`](http://openbsd.su/src/usr.sbin/httpd/) and its configuration. It does not apply to any other web servers.*

Is it possible to make runtime conditional configurations of the new OpenBSD http server `httpd`? A naïve example would be

```
server "myserver.com" {
  if $REMOTE_ADDR == "127.0.0.1" block drop
}
```

to disallow local access.

Another, perhaps more relevant and illuminating, example would be in the case I am implementing an interface to a remote service that runs from a specific place, then I would benefit from something like

```
remote_service1_ip = "192.168.0.1"
server "myserver.com" {
  location "/remote_service1_api/" {
    if $REMOTE_ADDR != $remote_service1_ip block drop
  }
}
```

If this is possible, what is the correct way of doing it?

More generally - there are a number of predefined macros specified in the [`man`-page of OpenBSD-`httpd.conf`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man5/httpd.conf.5) as described in the `block`:

```
$DOCUMENT_URI
    The request path.
$QUERY_STRING
    The optional query string of the request.
$REMOTE_ADDR
    The IP address of the connected client.
$REMOTE_PORT
    The TCP source port of the connected client.
$REMOTE_USER
    The remote user for HTTP authentication.
$REQUEST_URI
    The request path and optional query string.
$SERVER_ADDR
    The configured IP address of the server.
$SERVER_PORT
    The configured TCP server port of the server.
$SERVER_NAME
    The name of the server.
%n
    The capture index n of a string that was captured by the enclosing location match option.
```

and I would like to know how to use them. Using `$REMOTE_ADDR` in a redirection context seems rather silly to me, and I guess there should be something else to use them for, but I can't find or understand any such use case in the documentation.

Comment: What are you trying to do, exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I have updated the question with the specific case and the general one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

while `httpd` supports using [`patterns`](http://man.openbsd.org/OpenBSD-current/man7/patterns.7) in the context of some keywords (`alias match`, `location match`, `server match`) the functionality you are looking for is not implemented in `httpd`.

i see two ways to realize your intentions:

1. crosspost on the `openbsd-misc` mailing list - one of the authors of `httpd` might pick you up there
2. use [`pf`](http://www.openbsd.org/faq/pf/) to firewall. i do strongly recommend this way for various reasons including

   - higher grade of protection against denial-of-service types of attacks as the application (`httpd`) does not have to take any load
   - packets from clients can be inspected and blocked on a global (`IP`) wide level - i.e. a flooding client may not connect to the `ssh` port

i my opinion, `pf` can be a very satisfying thing to learn.

besides, i suspect a possible answer to an according post on `openbsd-misc` to be similar to my recommendation :)